# Reviews section seems to be duplicating on some products

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am completly miffed. I'm new to using liquid but not new to programming, it's my day job. Below we have a snippet of the `product-template.liquid` file. Hopefully, it looks familiar to folk rather than me pasting the whole file. That being said, [here's a link to a paste of it.](https://dpaste.com/7KETAAG2F)

```
{% else %}
  <div class="product-description rte" itemprop="description">
    {{ product.description }}
  </div>
{% endunless %}
          
<div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}</div>
```

I wanted to add a *footer* onto descriptions as there's some copy pasted text at the bottom of every product description.

So I changed the above to the the following:

```
{% else %}
  <div class="product-description rte" itemprop="description">
    {{ product.description }}
  </div>
{% endunless %}

<p>Here's my footer text.</p>
          
<div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}</div>
```

This seemed to do the job until I noticed the duplication of the review sections. The content of the `<p>` tag was in between the two review sections prior to this screenshot:
[image: review duplication]

I removed the `<p>` tag so that it was back to its original state. However, the review duplication is still there.

Inspecting the page shows one review section nested in the product description div and another one outside of it.

To make matters worse, this issue doesn't seem to be repeatable as far as I can see. I've looked at a product where there is the duplication and another product where there isn't duplication, yet no difference as far as I can see.

Either I'm completely blind in what I returned the code too or maybe Shopify takes time to propagate these changes to templates to each product?

It's worth mentioning, maybe, that I did these code changes using their site code editor.

#### Update 1

I've worked out the repeatable part. I'm making these changes whilst my partner is creating her products for the site. By my estimations the code changes I made and the products she's added after that point have the review duplication. It seems to be that products prior do not exhibit the duplication issue.

#### Update 2

Update 1 might not be the case. I duplicated a product where there was not a duplicate review section. The duplicate also showed that there was just one review section. Time of creation doesn't seem to have an impact.

Comment: I notice at the end of the file that you linked to that there is an `endschema` Liquid tag without an opening `schema` tag. Is this just because you removed the section settings for the example? If not, the file is currently un-saveable as Shopify isn't able to compile it, so it may be running the template as the last-compiled version

Comment: Yes @DaveB it was just for the example.